# How to save and load multiple select with Tbselect2 yii booster

Tags: php, yii

i have multiple select using Tbselect2 yii booster. i have success create in _form but failed when save data an load for update form. when i save the form the value which i choose in Tbselect2 is not save to database (null). Pleaes help me to how to save and load data in Tbselect2 yii booster. This isi my code

```
//my code in _form
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2',array(
            'asDropDownList' => true,
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'hobi',
                      'options'  => array(
                        'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('Hobi'),
                        'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' '),
                         'width'=>'500px',
                    'allowClear'=>true,
                    ),

                  'data'=>CHtml::listData(Hobi::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'nm_hobi ASC')),
                            'nm_hobi','nm_hobi'
                            ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'multiple'=>'multiple',
                  ),
                )); //call hobi name from model Hobi

//my code in controller
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Tbnasabah;
        if(isset($_POST['Tbnasabah']))
        {           
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Tbnasabah'];
            if($model->save())

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idnasabah));
        }
        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Tbnasabah']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Tbnasabah'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idnasabah));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
            //  $model->hobi=$model->hobi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Tbnasabah;
    if(isset($_POST['Tbnasabah']))
    {   
        $_POST['Tbnasabah']['hobi'] = $model->hobi;
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Tbnasabah'];
        if($model->save())

            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idnasabah));
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: i have try but still not save in database, the field in database is null , action create not success save data to database, anyone can help me

Comment: public function actionCreate()
 {
     $model=new Tbnasabah;
    if(isset($_POST['Tbnasabah']))
    {   
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Tbnasabah'];
     if($_POST['Tbnasabah']['hobi'] !=='')
                                $model->hobi=implode(',',$_POST['Tbnasabah']['hobi']);//converting to string...
     if($model->save())

      $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idnasabah));
    }
     $model->hobi=explode(',',$_POST['Tbnasabah']['hobi'] );//converting to array...
    $this->render('create',array(
     'model'=>$model,
    ));

 
 }  its work for me